# How to access the query arguments in transformResponse with redux toolkit query (RTKQ)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am making a POST call using the RTK query. I am able to pass the payload data to my query, But I want to access the query arguments 'id' inside my `transformResponse` function. but found no ways to do so.

below is my code

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'api',
  
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/fakeApi' }),
 
  endpoints: builder => ({
    
    getPosts: builder.query({
      
      query: ({id}) => ({ url, method: 'POST', body: { id } }),
      transformResponse: (response) => { console.log(response, id) } //How can I access the 'id' from query here?
    })
  })
})
```

How can I access the query payload inside the `transformResopnse` function ?

I also tries passing the `arg` to transformResponse function but arg is undefined for me.

```
(response, meta, arg)
```

arg is undefined for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are using at least the version `v1.7.0` of [`redux-toolkit`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.7.0)

Here is the parameters that takes `transformResponse`

```
(
  baseQueryReturnValue: unknown,
  meta: unknown,
  arg: unknown
)
```

You can use:

- the third argument to get `arg` that contain your id

```
transformResponse: (response, meta, arg) => {
  console.log(response, meta, arg)
}
```

Comment: I tries this but arg is undefined for me

Comment: have you try to use meta ?

Comment: yes, meta contains request and response object but no payload data

Comment: Are you using at least the version 1.7.0  https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/releases/tag/v1.7.0 ?

Comment: No, I am using version 1.6.1 of Toolkit.

Comment: Please upgrade this is why it does not work

Comment: I've specify it in the response